# How do I get the current ASP.NET theme from HttpContext.Current?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, themes

I am using AJAX to load a user control from server side within an HTTP Handler. To do this, I am creating a new page object and executing the user control server side to generate raw HTML, like so:

```
   Dim page As New Page()
   Dim frm As New HtmlForm
   Dim commentTag As String = "CaptureText"
   Dim viewControl As UserControl = CType(page.LoadControl(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(String.Format("~/Help/{0}.ascx",Topic))), UserControl)
   page.Controls.Add(frm)
   frm.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(String.Format("<!-- {0} -->", commentTag)))
   frm.Controls.Add(viewControl)
   frm.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(String.Format("<!-- /{0} -->", commentTag)))

   Dim writer As New StringWriter()
   context.Server.Execute(page, writer, False)
   context.Response.ContentType = "text/html"
   context.Response.Write(GetContents(writer.ToString, commentTag))
```

GetContents() is simply a function that returns everything between the 2 hard-coded HTML comments, which is effectively only the HTML of my UserControl.

The issue I am having is that some of these server controls require ASP.NET theme support. I found a way to do it by adding the following lines after the page declaration:

```
   page.Theme = "Theme3"
   page.Controls.Add(New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead())
```

This works like a charm when hard-coded with a theme name. However, I would like to get the theme name from the current context. All of the examples I have seen online require you to have a page object in order to get the name of the theme. But I am starting with a new page that has no theme.

So my question is whether there is a way to load the theme name from somewhere in HttpContext or is the only way to load this on the server side by passing the theme name from the client via AJAX?

Comment: what about storing of the Theme in the Session state?

Answer (score 4):

```
(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page).Theme;
```

Or
Assuming that you are using a default theme by specifying it in Pages section

```
PagesSection pages = (PagesSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/pages");

//use the them  via  pages.Theme
```

Comment: I had thought of this. However, since I am executing the statement from within a generic HTTP Handler it cannot be cast as type page. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Your second idea is also a handy piece of code to have. However, it means that this handler will have to change if I change the way themes are applied in the future. Right now there is some conditional logic that applies them in the base page based on a variable stored in the user profile. I think I will just pass it from the client for now. That way future updates won't break it.

Comment: well handle code doesn't have to change, as this code is picking up the theme from the web.config.  And if you want the theme to be based on user, you can use either session or retrieve it from user's profile